# Get items from FIFO queue

Tags: jmeter, fifo

I am not an expert in Groovy. I am trying to use the items from FIFO queue into an http request in jmeter. I am trying to get from FIFO queue but, it gets the list. I want to use JSR223 pre processor and need help.

How can i get each item from the list separately.

Answer (score 1):

Just call the following function as many times as there are items in the queue:

```
kg.apc.jmeter.modifiers.FifoMap.getInstance().pop('some-queue')
```

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InterThreadCommunication/)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: I  wont have the count of items in advance. it depends on the thread number and Loops. And, isnt it that fifoPop picks values as it comes into the queue whereas fifo get fetches everything in queue. What is advisable?

Comment: You can get the number of threads and loops in Groovy. fifoPop gets the item and removes it from the queue, fifoGet gets the item at doesn't remove it from the queue

Comment: i tried using jsr223 sampler to get the IDs from queue using the for loop based on the size of the queue and this ID would be used in a JDBC sampler that follows but, probably it is not the right approach to use for loop. Any suggestions?